# NgModuleFactoryLoader.load() is not able to find the module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink, angular-lazyloading

[Please refer my project structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbnnZ.png) I have create a project with multiple lazy loaded nested modules.

1. On the application start up AppModule is loaded
2. When the user clicks on login button LoginModule is loaded
3. If the user exists i.e if login is successful IntegratedPmntsModule which is another feature module of AppModule should be lazily loaded from login-routing.module.ts. It is loading IntegratedPmntsModule perfectly with 'button routerLink='integratePayments' class="pmntButton"' but that's not what i want.

My requirement here is to conditionally load the feature child module as shown in the component login.component.ts, when the user login is failed he should be navigated to login(its working fine as LoginModule is already lazy loaded) and when login is successful user should be navigated to IntegratedPaymentsComponent present in IntegratedPmntsModule (which is not happening).

1. this.router.navigate(['integratedPayments']); -- is giving 'Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes 'integratedPayments'
2. I even tried loading the IntegratedPmntsModule using load() method of NgModuleFactoryLoader.load() which is giving 'module is not found error'

```js
login.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginFormGroup: FormGroup;
  customerModel:CustomerLoginModel = new CustomerLoginModel();
  userExist: Boolean = true;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router, private readonly loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginFormGroup = new FormGroup({
      customerId: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(20),Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$')]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)])
    })
  }
  submitLoginForm(formGroup: FormGroup): any{
   
   this.customerModel.setCustomerId(formGroup.value.customerId);
   this.customerModel.setPassword(formGroup.value.password);
   this.loginService.authenticateCustomer(this.customerModel).subscribe(
     response=>{
       this.userExist=response},
      error=>{
        console.log(error)
      }
    );
      if(this.userExist){
          //this.loader.load('./app/integrate-pmnts-module/integrate-pmnts.module#IntegratePmntsModule').
          //then(factory =>this.router.navigate(['integratedPayments']));
          this.router.navigate(['integratedPayments']);
      }
      else
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }

}
```

```js
app-routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginauthGuard } from './login/loginauth.guard';


const routes: Routes = [
 
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(mdule=>mdule.LoginModule),
  },
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```js
login-routing.module.ts


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    //canDeactivate: [LoginauthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'integratedPayments',
    loadChildren: () => import('../integrate-pmnts-module/integrate-pmnts.module').then(mdule=>mdule.IntegratePmntsModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule { 

}
```

```html
login.component.html


<html>
    <form [formGroup]="loginFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="submitLoginForm(loginFormGroup)"> 
            Customer Id:<input type="text" formControlName="customerId" placeholder="Enter Customer ID"><br><br>
            Password: <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Enter Password"><br><br>
            <div *ngIf='!userExist'>
                Please enter valid credentials!
            </div><br><br>
        <button class="pmntButton">Login</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

```js
integratepayments-routing.module.ts


const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: IntegratedPaymentsComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'eftPaymentsPage',
      loadChildren: () => import('src/app/integrate-pmnts-module/eft-payments-module/eft-payments-module').then(mod=>mod.EftPaymentsModuleModule)
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class IntegratedPaymentsRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Use 'this.router.navigate(['login','integratedPayments']);'  when user is authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `integratedPayments` route is a **child** of `login` route, you should use: `this.router.navigateByUrl('login/integratedPayments')`.

This might not still work though, because the routes from `login-routing.module.ts` are defined as follows:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    //canDeactivate: [LoginauthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'integratedPayments',
    loadChildren: () => import('../integrate-pmnts-module/integrate-pmnts.module').then(mdule=>mdule.IntegratePmntsModule)
  }
];
```

which means that the first route (`path: ''`) will **always match**. What you can do in order to avoid this is to add the `pathMatch: 'full'` option:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'integratedPayments',
    loadChildren: () => import('../integrate-pmnts-module/integrate-pmnts.module').then(mdule=>mdule.IntegratePmntsModule)
  }
];
```

---

> perfectly with 'button routerLink='integratePayments' class="pmntButton"'

this is because of how `RouterLink` directive works internally.

Let's see [what happens](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L206-L226) when you click on a button which has this directive:

```js
@HostListener('click')
  onClick(): boolean {
    const extras = {
      skipLocationChange: attrBoolValue(this.skipLocationChange),
      replaceUrl: attrBoolValue(this.replaceUrl),
      state: this.state,
    };
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.urlTree, extras);
    return true;
  }

  get urlTree(): UrlTree {
    return this.router.createUrlTree(this.commands, {
      relativeTo: this.route, // !
      queryParams: this.queryParams,
      fragment: this.fragment,
      preserveQueryParams: attrBoolValue(this.preserve),
      queryParamsHandling: this.queryParamsHandling,
      preserveFragment: attrBoolValue(this.preserveFragment),
    });
  }
```

as you can see, it's using `relativeTo` option. `this.route` is injected as [`private route: ActivatedRoute`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L171).

What this means is that you can make it work with `this.router.navigate(['integratedPayments']);` from you login component.

You'll have to first inject the `ActivatedRoute` inside login component and then add the `relativeTo` option to `route.navigate`:

```js
this.router.navigate(['integratedPayments'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Comment: Hey Andrei, Thank you so much for your reply. It is a very clear explanation and it actually worked for me!!

Comment: I’m glad I could help!